# iOS: Detect the source of the iOS app installation programmatically (inside the installed app)

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I would like to know if there is a way to detect how the user has found my app in the AppStore.
For example if there is some parameter that I can concatenate to the URL of my app in the AppStore and get it inside the installed app.

It might be http://itunes.apple.com/app/SOME-APP-ID?mt=8**&source=Facebook**
In the example from above I would like to receive the "Facebook" string inside the app...

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

You should ask Apple by [opening a Radar](http://bugreporter.apple.com/), though I wouldn't hold your breath... We've been waiting for analytics since 2008!

Answer (score 3):

I have a friend who adds a step, using Google Analytics [URL Builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867&topic=1032998&ctx=topic) to send users to his website with an auto-redirect from there to his appstore link. I haven't actually tried it myself, but he claims it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna go with no.....you would need the cooperation of Apple's servers, itunes, and their IPA format.