# I want get installation source code after installation iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Hey I am working on iOS app .
And i want to get installation source code after installed in app.
I have read this -

[iOS: Detect the source of the iOS app installation programmatically (inside the installed app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090312/ios-detect-the-source-of-the-ios-app-installation)

But i don't get any solution if it is possible so , please provide me solution .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use a service such as Branch.io.

Comment: can you please explain it and i don't want to use any purchased third api

Comment: Without using a 3rd-party, you would have to implement all that yourself.  If you don't even understand the problem, no Stack Overflow answer is going to help you.

Comment: thats why i am asking on Stack Overflow  because  i want suggestion to solve this problem not use any third party api . And Can you please tell me how to do solve this

Comment: This is not the appropriate forum for such a question.  I would look at services such as Branch.io (they are not the only service) and read about how they work.  Perhaps you'll find enough direction to roll your own.